# rewriting pseudocode to Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write the pseudo code from beneath into a Haskell function.
I was able to write the isValid function, which takes an exam and the current schedule and checks if it the exam would fit into the current schedule.
This is my current attempt:

```
addexam currentSchedule [] = currentSchedule
addexam currentSchedule listOfExams = let result = []
                                          res = fillRes currentSchedule listOfExams
                                       in (res: result)

fillRes currentSchedule (x:xs) | isValid x currentSchedule = addexam (x:currentSchedule) xs
                               | otherwise = addexam currentSchedule []
```

I know that in my version is not correct but I completely understand what is missing. Also I get this error:

```
 Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t ~ [t]
    Expected type: [t] -> [t] -> t
      Actual type: [t] -> [t] -> [t]
    Relevant bindings include
      res :: t (bound at Server.hs:170:43)
      listOfExams :: [t] (bound at Server.hs:169:25)
      currentSchedule :: [t] (bound at Server.hs:169:9)
      addexam :: [t] -> [t] -> [t] (bound at Server.hs:168:1)
    In the expression: fillRes currentSchedule listOfExams
    In an equation for ‘res’: res = fillRes currentSchedule listOfExams
    In the expression:
      let
        result = []
        res = fillRes currentSchedule listOfExams
      in (res : result)
```

Pseudo-Code :

```
addExam (currentSchedule, examsLeft):
    if examsLeft.empty():
        return [currentSchedule]
    doodle = examsLeft[0]
    results = []
    for each possible-exam in doodle
        if is-valid (possible-exam, currentSchedule):
            res = addExam (currentSchedule.append(possible-exam), examsLeft[1:])
        results.append(res)
    return results
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some type confusion inside your pseudo-code which is carrying over to your Haskell example and since you have no type annotations, it makes the code hard to reason about, and makes the error messages especially opaque.

Based on what I *think* you're trying to do, here's an attempt at refining your `addExam` function in Haskell.

First we need to define the types. From what I infer from your description, you've got a `PossibleExam` type that will probably have things like Time and Subject fields down the road, but for the example, we only need a type constructor:

```hs
data PossibleExam = PossibleExam -- you'll probably have other fields like Time, Subject, etc.
```

I'm assuming that your `Exam` type is just a list of `PossibleExams`, most likely split up by common subjects.

```hs
type Exam = [PossibleExam]
```

I'm also assuming that the `Schedule` type is a list of `PossibleExams`, split up by times to avoid overlap.

```hs
type Schedule = [PossibleExam]
```

You'll avoid a lot of problems by starting off with type signatures on the functions you're creating. Based on my assumptions above, `addExam` will have a shape like this:

```hs
addExam :: Schedule -> [Exam] -> Schedule
```

If there are no exams left to add, we can return the current Schedule:

```hs
addExam currentSchedule [] =
  currentSchedule
```

And if there are exams left to add, we can do so by using the yet-to-be-defined `tryAddExam` function (I'll leave it as an exercise to you to figure out what you want to do in case an exam can't be added):

```hs
addExam currentSchedule (doodle:examsLeft) =
  case tryAddExam currentSchedule doodle of
    Just newSchedule ->
      addExam newSchedule examsLeft
    Nothing -> 
      undefined -- What do you do if the exam won't fit?
```

The `tryAddExam` function can return a `Maybe Schedule` that represents success with a `Just Schedule` or failure with `Nothing`:

```hs
tryAddExam :: Schedule -> Exam -> Maybe Schedule
```

If we've exhausted all possible exams, then we return a failure:

```hs
tryAddExam currentSchedule [] =
  Nothing
```

Otherwise, if there are exams left to attempt, we use your `isValid` function to test whether we can add them and if so, add them to the current schedule:

```hs
tryAddExam currentSchedule (possibleExam:rest) =
  if isValid possibleExam currentSchedule then
    Just $ possibleExam : currentSchedule
  else
    tryAddExam currentSchedule rest
```

Hopefully I'm on the right track with your intentions inside the pseudo-code, overlooking some of the array and type confusion in the example. The main thing to get across here is the importance of clearly defining your types and function signatures. Let the types guide you.

Comment: Trying to add something and possibly failing typically results in a `Maybe` in idiomatic code, rather than a flagged value. Of course, it all depends on how it's to be used.

Comment: Good point, @dfeuer, I've changed my answer to be a bit more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

A list can not be its own element in Haskell. Even in languages where you can construct such a construct, the only thing you could know about such a thing is that it is a list which is its own element.

On one hand, from your 2nd equation, what `fillRes` returns is an element of a list that `addexam` returns.

On the other hand, from your 3rd equation, what `addexam` returns is the same thing as what `fillRes` returns. Hence the error.

You can fix it by changing `:` into `++`, as

```
addexam currentSchedule listOfExams = let result = []
                                          res = fillRes currentSchedule listOfExams
                                       in res ++ result
```

Of course `res ++ []` is just `res`, and `let x = ... in x` is just `...` (when `x` isn't referred to inside the `...` expression).